# Using @section inside Razor Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

We are trying to setup Sections of our layout to be Required but configurable based on the individual page. At the moment we do this with a Section.

```
@section FloatingNav {
    <h1>@Model.Name <span class="release-year">@Model.AverageRating</span></h1>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#episodes">Episodes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#episodes">Cast</a></li>
        <li>Reviews</li>
        <li>Related</li>
    </ul>
}
```

This requires you to setup this block in every new page but i wanted to make this process easier with some defaults and options to configure using a partial view. I was hoping to setup a Razor helper such as this.

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html
@helper FloatingNav(string name, int rating) {
    @section FloatingNav {
        <h1>
            name <span class="release-year">rating</span></h1>
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#episodes">Episodes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#episodes">Cast</a></li>
            <li>Reviews</li>
            <li>Related</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
@helper FloatingNav(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string viewName) {
    @section FloatingNav {
        @html.Partial(viewName)
    }
}
@helper FloatingNav(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string viewName, object model) {
    @section FloatingNav {
        @html.Partial(viewName, model)
    }
}
```

So the syntax to implement would be something like

```
@Layout.FloatingNav(@Model.Name, @Model.AverageRating)
```

or

```
@Layout.FloatingNav("_SimpleNav", @Model)
```

The issue though is that it seems the Razor Helpers do not understand the section syntax. Is there a way to include sections in Razor Helpers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.

The `@helper` and `@section` syntax are special directives for compiling pages.

A `HelperResult` (a helper) doesn't know how to define a section.

The [DefineSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.definesection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method belongs to a `WebPageBase`.

You might have to come at this from a different direction. Using partial views instead of helpers would probably fix this problem.