# Asp.Net MVC Helper: create a global helper for loading view with or without layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper, razorgenerator

I want to create a application in which if there is Ajax call it return Partial view and if it is a page refresh it return with layout and render script. But the problem is partial view won't render sections, for that I have created a MVC helper in APP_Code as :

```
 @helper AddSection(Func<object, object> content)
 {
   if (IsAjaxRequest)
   {
        @content(null);
   }
   else
   {
        @section scripts {
            @content(null);
        }
   }
}
```

When I am calling it in my view I am getting the bellow error :

```
CS0103: The name 'DefineSection' does not exist in the current context
Line 71: #line hidden
Line 72: DefineSection("scripts", () => {
Line 73:
```

I tried many things but this error is still there, I also searched a lot but couldn't found the solution.

Comment: Just to make things clear, you want to call the same action twice. One time with a standard get request and one time with an xhr ajax request?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched a lot, and found that section inside helper are not possible. below are the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22977735/5179246

The @helper and @section syntax are special directives for compiling pages.

A HelperResult (a helper) doesn't know how to define a section.

The [DefineSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.webpagebase.definesection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method belongs to a WebPageBase.

You might have to come at this from a different direction. Using partial views instead of helpers would probably fix this problem.

**You can use nested layout..The inner layout is just to render body and script.**

Answer (score 0):

You could check the request header (as explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864179/how-to-know-if-the-request-is-ajax-in-asp-net-mvc)). Check the `X-Requested-With`, if it says `XMLHttpRequest` it should be an XHR (Ajax) request.

In your controller you could return a `PartialView` in the same method.

```
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
    Boolean IsAjax = false; //check the request header

    if (IsAjax) 
    {
        ViewBag.UseLayout = false;
        return PartialView("PartialView");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("View");
    }
}
```

Inside your View you could read the `ViewBag.UseLayout` and decide to render the complete layout with all sections or not:

```
@{
    if (ViewBag.UseLayout == null || ViewBag.UseLayout) {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    else {
        Layout = null;
    }
}
```

You could extend that to the `ViewStart.cshtml`, with null checking of the ViewBag so this would be applied to all views.

Comment: I already knew whether to load partial view or not, the problem is if it is partial I want to load script section without rendering sections, and if it is full view section should be rendered.

Comment: I dont think it would load a partial view directly from the server through an ajax call....

Comment: You will have to come back to the View(The ajax response), then load the partilal view accordingly from the view.